# Image inside of the div is displayed outside of it

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

I have a dynamically generated unordered list (`<ul>`),  located inside of the div, which I fill in with list items (`<li>`) which contain images . The div containing this unordered list has background color which supposed to be beside the dynamically created buttons-images. How do I do this?

The id of div containing this unordered list is `#description`.

The repository with the page is here: https://github.com/Kekton/Skilet19

P.S. In prospect, it should support IE6. If you notice any issues with my code, please let me know.

Comment: it's a lot of job for us, don't you think ? going to your repository, download stuffs, check issue ... why you don't do this effort and put everything here ?

Comment: I didn't do this because you might have thought that there are issues because the rules that as I think are applied to the images are not in effect because they're:
1) overridden by others
2) don't match this element
3) something else

I gave you keywords which can allow you easily find whatever you're interested in without installation of the whole project. No one forces you to install everything but I gave you such possibility.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem that I had was actually in applying overflow: auto to each of images in the list, not to the whole list.

You can check the history of changes on GitHub. This problem was solved on in the following commit:
https://github.com/Kekton/Skilet19/commit/e5e90d9a59fb4ab0345501a0ad79da106146d2dd

The repository before this commit: https://github.com/Kekton/Skilet19/tree/bb11b0120c1e3b5501c8c28dd53b86ec9735bfd3

The repository after this commit:
https://github.com/Kekton/Skilet19/tree/e5e90d9a59fb4ab0345501a0ad79da106146d2dd